# What is the best way to auto send/scedule emails on a click event

Tags: javascript, firebase, email

I would like to know how I can automate emails from a JS (weekly) programm and also when interacting with a click event. The new email addresses will be added to the app daily and will be saved to google firestore.

Techonolgies I am using:

- Javascript
- Firebase
- Vue.js

Comment: You can't send emails from a client-side web app. You'd need a backend server to do it and perhaps a scheduler if you're running them on schedule. The question how to do any of that has already been answered, and it's too vague to answer in one question as it'd turn into a tutorial given it does not address a specific issue you're facing :-)

Comment: @Adriani6 Firebase is the server. Backend-as-a-Service (BaaS)

Comment: My bad! I mixed it up with Firestore for some reason... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger some function on click just add click event to your app and inside it call firebase callable function

> exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
> // ...
> });
> as you can see [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

And for schedule calls firebase has [schedule functions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

And send emails with nodemailer added to that functions like:

```
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
  
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'Test <test@example.com>',
            to: dest,
            subject: 'Test subj',
            html: `Some html text`
        };

        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro: any, info: any) => {
            if(erro){
                return res.send(erro.toString());
            }
            return res.send(req.body);
        });
    });    
});
```